# Matrix multiplation program

Tags: c

I am trying to build a program which multiplies a matrix by itself and puts the answer in another matrix. I built the matrix from a 2 dimension array:

```
for (int a = 0; a < k; a++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Matsize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Matsize; j++) {
            ScalarSum += (Matrix[i][j]*Matrix[j][i]);
            New_Matrix[i][j] = ScalarSum;
        }
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < Matsize; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < Matsize ; j++) {
        printf("%d ", New_Matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

k in the first line is an integer that has been scanned from the user which stands for how many times to multiply the matrix by itself. Matrix is the original matrix, New_Matrix is the matrix which receives the multiplication.
Matsize is the size of the matrix. (if Matsize is 3 the matrix is 3x3) 
The problem is that I get wrong numbers every time I'm trying to print the new matrix.

Comment: Where are `Matrix`, `Matsize`, `New_Matrix`, and `ScalarSum` declared and initialized? What is the purpose of the outer loop over `a`?

Comment: `Initialize ScalarSum = 0;`

Comment: its purpose is to run as many times as the user defines, the outer loop "for(int a = 0; a < k ; a++)" need to limit the times of the multiplication. so if the user says to multiply the matrix 4 times, k is 4.
Matrix is the first array which is a 2 dimension array. Matrix,Matsize,New_Matrix and ScalarSum are declared in the main block which is a bit above the lines of codes that I published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to initialize `ScalarSum` sometimes; right now, it accumulates products forever.

Apart from that, computation of `NewMatrix[i][j]` requires yet another loop.

And regarding your repeated squaring: You never copy the result from `NewMatrix` back to `Matrix`.

I suspect you mostly lost overview. Therefore I urge you write suitable functions, e.g., `Multiply(A,B,C)` to compute the product of `A`and `B` into `C` (where `A` *may* be the same as `B`).